# Formating 500giga hard disk

Tags: performance

I planning to buy a new labtop 500giga hard-disk no system, And was thinking to setup windows xp on drive C: 50g for windows and 50 for ubuntu file system.

My question should I make one volume for the rest 400G or make 4 Volumes 100 each?

Another Question: I'm Planning to encrypt all my files, but don't know if I made one 400g volume should encrypt all of it with true crypt or better make containers on it, and how big should the containers be 50Giga each or 100Giga to get best performance. thanks

Comment: Why 100GB parts? Are you referring to the 48Bit LBA phenomen of Windows XP? If yes: That shouldn't matter today. And if it does, you can't use your setup anyway.

[how to check 48bit lba support](http://superuser.com/questions/356409/how-do-i-get-48-bit-lba-bios-support)

Comment: so final answer I should make 400Giga volume ext4, about truecrypt encrypt the whole partition or better make 300Giga container and leave the other 100Giga un-encrypted. Hint:the reason I want to encrypt files as all of you know laptops are easy to stolen or lost!

Answer (score 0):

400GB is small these days.  Why would you want to split it up?  Keep it as a single volume.

I don't see the need to encypt ALL files.  Why not just keep the ones that need to remain private in a container file, and leave the rest as normal unencrypted files.  Less hassles in the long run.

Comment: 'll 400GB is ok, but all the files will be personal I dont put movies, songs or games all ubuntu will be for my personal stuff, so I hve to encrypt all of it.